# Pandas plot a repeating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to graph a pandas dataframe that contains 2 columns as shown below:

```
For i in data1:
  for j in data2:
      traces.append(
           go.Scatter(
                 x=df['A'],
                  y=df['B']
               )
           )
```

plot

[image: tab]

Column A has repeating values.  When I Plot them it plots the first points correctly (column 'A' 1,2,3 column 'B' 2,5,6) but when it goes to plot the second set of repeating values 'A' 1,2,3 'B' 4,2,3 it draws a line from 'B' point 6 to the next point on 'B' point 2.  It doesn't start again as shown below.

from this:

[image: Not]

to this:

[image: Yes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to plot each three lines separately:

```
ax = plt.axes()
df['span'] = df.index // 3 # Assign identical markers to each span
df.groupby('span').apply(lambda x: x.plot(x='A', y='B', legend=False, ax=ax)
plt.show() # If not in ipython
```

Comment: This is definitely a lot more clean and scalable. +1

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the same solution as @DYZ. Still posting as I had already tried this.

```
ax = df.iloc[:3, [0,1]].plot('A', 'B')
df.iloc[3:6, [0,1]].plot('A', 'B',ax = ax)
df.iloc[6:9, [0,1]].plot('A', 'B',ax = ax)
```

Essentially they are three plots but on the same axis so they overlap.