# Pandas plot a repeating dataframe issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having some problems with plotting a Pandas dataframe with repeating range on x-axis after every 17 points. It doesn't start from new line after repetition. How to fix this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('BS.xlsx')
plt.plot(df.BZ, df.energy)
plt.show()
```

[Repeating Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfLEY.png)

Comment: Please provide the code you used, so people have more information to help you with.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not start from new line"? Please explain your end goal

Comment: @G.Jan thank you for reply. Actually i wanted a separate lines for each same range of df.BZ column with respect to df.energy.

Comment: @sajid You are getting the line connected between the same range (df.BZ) on xaxis because of line plot. In pandas.df.plot the default kind is "line". Try changing the kind of plot. For example, try plt.plot.scatter(df.BZ,df.energy)
Is that something that will work for you?

Comment: @G.Jan plt.plot.scatter (df.BZ,df.energy) command not wotking. I tried plt.scatter (df.BZ, df.energy) but i am interested in line plot. Please see the following link l need that kind of solution but in my case that's not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798576/pandas-plot-a-repeating-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Based on the df provided. You can try as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('BS.xlsx')
df['range']= df.index//17
ax = plt.axes()
df.groupby('range').apply(lambda x:x.plot(x='BZ', y= 'energy', legend = False, ax=ax))
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. But I am getting so many same warning messages 
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Comment: @sajid try the updated version above. Should fix it